# How to show transitivity of big-theta?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

If I were to have functions f(x), g(x), and h(x) such  that f(x) is Θ(g(x)) and g(x)  is Θ(h(x)). How would I show that f(x) is Θ(h(x)). Would I go about this by showing that f(x) is both big-o and big-omega of h(x). And if so, how would I go about doing that.

Comment: Yep, that's a very reasonable way to prove it. This is a great place to pull out the formal definitions of big-O and big-Omega notation.

Answer (score 1):

> Would I go about this by showing that f(x) is both big-o and big-omega of h(x)?

Yes, you can do that.

> And if so, how would I go about doing that?

One way is to use the definitions of Big O and Big Omega.

Proving big O (big Omega is similar):

According to the [definition of big Theta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations), `f(n) = Θ(g(n))` [iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) `f(n) = O(g(n))` **and** `f(n) = Ω(g(n))`.

Since `f(n) = O(g(n))`, then according to the definition of big O, there exist `c_0 > 0` and `N_0 > 0` such that for every `n > N_0`,

(1) `f(n) <= c_0 * g(n)`

Similarly, since `g(n) = O(h(n))`, then according to the definition of big O, there exist `c_1 > 0` and `N_1 > 0` such that for every `n > N_1`,

(2) `g(n) <= c_1 * h(n)`

If we define `N_2 = max{N_0, N_1}`, and `c_2 = c_0 * c_1`, then for every `n > N_2` we get:

```
f(n) <= c_0 * g(n) <= c_0 * c_1 * h(n) = c_2 * h(n)
```

The first inequality holds because `n > N_0` (since `n > N_2`) and we can use (1). The second inequality holds since `n > N_1` and we can use (2).

Thus `f(n) = O(h(n))` according to the definition.

After we show that `f(n) = Ω(h(n))`, then we can conclude that `f(n) = Θ(h(x))` according to the definition of big Theta.